# What is the difference between mqsc end vs mqsc quit vs mqsc exit in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am curious to know the difference between mqsc end vs mqsc quit vs mqsc exit in IBM Websphere MQ. A detailed explanation on these command could be helpful.

Comment: See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21621085 for an example with `END` and `exit`. According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm `exit` and `quit` seem to have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual page for runmqsc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm?lang=en) states that `end`, `exit` and `quit` are synonyms:

> To stop the runmqsc command, use the end command. You can also use the
>   exit or the quit command.

As for the part about "a detailed explanation on these command could be helpful," I'm not sure how much more detail would be appropriate.  I could write a sonnet or something if you think it would be useful.  :-)

Comment: ha ha ha :-) . Thank you Rob. Happy to know that everything works the same way.

Comment: It's quite natural for people to type quit or exit or bye to end a console session. It's good that MQSC has these additional commands now.